# Unable to connect cloud postgres database instance from mule 4

Tags: postgresql, mule, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am new to mule and wanted to connect `postgres` instance created on `heroku` in `mule4`.

DB configuration is as below

```
<db:config name="DB-conf" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="5748d366-caa3-47c1-9a58-825a674dc637" >
    <db:generic-connection url="jdbc:postgresql://sccdlqszewilhy:7a8510f34e7625758fa0babcc9bcfdc404bfc27b8e39501ec177677bb370329a@ec2-54-243-47-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dnaiaif9337or" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" user="sccdlqszewilhy" password="7a8510f34e7625758fa0babcc9bcfdc404bfc27b8e39501ec177677bb370329a"/>
</db:config>
```

**Gives me below error:**

> org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: Could not obtain connection from data source
>     org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: Could not obtain connection from data source
>     Caused by: org.mule.extension.db.api.exception.connection.ConnectionCreationException: Could not obtain connection from data source
>     Caused by: org.mule.runtime.extension.api.exception.ModuleException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:postgresql://sccdlqszewilhy:7a8510f34e7625758fa0babcc9bcfdc404bfc27b8e39501ec177677bb370329a@ec2-54-243-47-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dnaiaif9337or : The connection attempt failed.
>     Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:postgresql://sccdlqszewilhy:7a8510f34e7625758fa0babcc9bcfdc404bfc27b8e39501ec177677bb370329a@ec2-54-243-47-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dnaiaif9337or : The connection attempt failed.
>       at org.mule.extension.db.internal.domain.connection.JdbcConnectionFactory.createConnection(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:57)
>       at org.mule.extension.db.internal.domain.connection.DbConnectionProvider.connect(DbConnectionProvider.java:139)
>       at org.mule.extension.db.internal.domain.connection.DbConnectionProvider.connect(DbConnectionProvider.java:71)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.DefaultConnectionProviderObjectBuilder.lambda$null$0(DefaultConnectionProviderObjectBuilder.java:133)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.lambda$withContextClassLoader$9(ClassUtils.java:860)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:227)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:915)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:879)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:859)
>       at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.DefaultConnectionProviderObjectBuilder.lambda$applyConnectionProviderClassLoaderProxy$1(DefaultConnectionProviderObjectBuilder.java:131)
>       at org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e53e62df.connect()
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.ConnectionProviderWrapper.connect(ConnectionProviderWrapper.java:64)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.ErrorTypeHandlerConnectionProviderWrapper.connect(ErrorTypeHandlerConnectionProviderWrapper.java:64)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.ConnectionProviderWrapper.connect(ConnectionProviderWrapper.java:64)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionProviderWrapper.connect(DefaultConnectionProviderWrapper.java:51)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.NullConnectionManagementStrategy.getConnectionHandler(NullConnectionManagementStrategy.java:40)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionManager.getConnection(DefaultConnectionManager.java:241)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionManager.lambda$testConnectivity$1(DefaultConnectionManager.java:160)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionManager.doTestConnectivity(DefaultConnectionManager.java:176)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionManager.testConnectivity(DefaultConnectionManager.java:152)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter$EagerConnectionManagerAdapter.testConnectivity(DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter.java:176)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter.testConnectivity(DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter.java:98)
>       at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.api.tooling.ExtensionConnectivityTestingStrategy.testConnectivity(ExtensionConnectivityTestingStrategy.java:82)
>       at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connectivity.DefaultConnectivityTestingService.testConnection(DefaultConnectivityTestingService.java:88)
>       at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyConnectivityTestingService.testConnection(LazyConnectivityTestingService.java:57)
>       at com.mulesoft.agent.services.tooling.MuleAgentConnectivityTestingService.testConnection(MuleAgentConnectivityTestingService.java:77)
>       at com.mulesoft.agent.external.handlers.tooling.ToolingRequestHandler.lambda$applicationTestConnection$11(ToolingRequestHandler.java:387)
>       at com.mulesoft.agent.util.ResponseHelper.response(ResponseHelper.java:88)
>       at com.mulesoft.agent.external.handlers.tooling.ToolingRequestHandler.applicationTestConnection(ToolingRequestHandler.java:386)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
>       at com.mulesoft.agent.rest.RequestLoggingFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Please show the complete error stack trace.

Comment: @AlejandroDobniewski, please see updated trace.

Comment: There is no root cause for the error for some reason. Is there nothing else in the error? Also which version of Mule and the DB connector was used?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the username and password from the url as you are already passing it differently. I used this reference to connect my heroku postgres instance. -

[How to connect heroku postgres to mulesoft](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/howto/connect-heroku-postgres-database-connector/)